# Error en tabla pl swl

Tags: plsql

Necesito crear un trigger que me almacene el número de filas que coincide en el atributo nombre.
El trigger creado es el siguiente:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER totalTareasUsuario
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON tareas
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    totalFilas NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- Obtener la cantidad de filas para el usuario específico
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO totalFilas
    FROM tareas
    WHERE nombre = :NEW.nombre;

    -- Imprimir o almacenar el resultado según tus necesidades
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total de filas para ' || :NEW.nombre || ': ' || totalFilas);
END;
/
```

El problema viene porque me da error tanto si le quito el FOR EACH ROW como si uso el :New …. Estoy muy perdido y ya no se por donde empezar¿sabríais darme alguna pista de dnd estoy cometiendo el error?
Gracias`

Comment: Agregue a la pregunta el error que se presenta, incluya el código numérico del error y el texto

Answer (score 0):

Ud. debe obtener el error de "tabla mutante" porque está haciendo una conteo sobre la misma tabla "tareas" que contiene el trigger, y eso NO se permite hacer cuando se usa la cláusula "FOR EACH ROW".